# Celery Django Body Encoding

Tags: django, redis, celery

Hi does anyone know how the body of a celery json is encoded before it is entered in the queue cache (i use Redis in my case).

```
{'body': 'W1sic2hhd25AdWJ4LnBoIiwge31dLCB7fSwgeyJjYWxsYmFja3MiOiBudWxsLCAiZXJyYmFja3MiOiBudWxsLCAiY2hhaW4iOiBudWxsLCAiY2hvcmQiOiBudWxsfV0=',
 'content-encoding': 'utf-8',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'headers': {'lang': 'py',
  'task': 'export_users',
  'id': '6e506f75-628e-4aa1-9703-c0185c8b3aaa',
  'shadow': None,
  'eta': None,
  'expires': None,
  'group': None,
  'retries': 0,
  'timelimit': [None, None],
  'root_id': '6e506f75-628e-4aa1-9703-c0185c8b3aaa',
  'parent_id': None,
  'argsrepr': "('<email@example.com>', {})",
  'kwargsrepr': '{}',
  'origin': 'gen187209@ubuntu'},
 'properties': {'correlation_id': '6e506f75-628e-4aa1-9703-c0185c8b3aaa',
  'reply_to': '403f7314-384a-30a3-a518-65911b7cba5c',
  'delivery_mode': 2,
  'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'},
  'priority': 0,
  'body_encoding': 'base64',
  'delivery_tag': 'dad6b5d3-c667-473e-a62c-0881a7349684'}}
```

Just a background I have a nodejs project which needs to trigger my celery (django). Background tasks are all in the django app but the trigger and the details will come from a nodejs app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to run celery tasks from nodejs app?   
Maybe you can just call it from command line like `celery call app.tasks.update_something`   

Don't know if nodejs is capable of running shell commands, but probably is

Comment: Its probably gonna be on a different server. Python has the tasks and the celery. NodeJS just need to trigger them with some input parameters.They both just have access to redis. Hesitant to open an external endpoint for this.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be simpler to use the nodejs celery client

https://github.com/mher/node-celery/blob/master/celery.js

to invoke a celery task from nodejs.